# Как правильно сделать разметку с NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

Всем привет!

Суть проблемы: имеется MainActivity.xml, в котором находятся контейнер для фрагментов и DrawerLayout. В контейнер для фрагментов подгружаются различные фрагменты, на некоторых из них нужен NavigationDrawer, а на некоторых не нужен, но при такой разметке на любом фрагменте можно открыть боковое меню левым свайпом, как правильно сделать разметку в таком случае? Сделать еще один контейнер, в который подгружать фрагменты, для которых не нужен NavigationDrawer?

[image: схема]

Comment: можно у вашего `NavigationDrawer` вызвать `setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)` ну и иконку в `INVISIBLE`

Comment: @ermak0ff как вариант, но это уже костыль будет)

Comment: да костыль отчасти, но что то я не видел готового решения из коробки))

Comment: По моему мнению, решение, предложенное @ermak0ff является наиболее логичным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите: вы сделали активити с боковым меню, чтобы на фрагментах в этом активити было одно и тоже боковое меню. В системе появился фрагмент, которому это боковое меню не нужно. Вывод: этот фрагмент не олжен быть фрагментом, а должен быть новой активити

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте активити, у которой будет только контейнер для фрагментов. А уже в разметке нужных вам фрагментов, сделайте `DrawerLayout` c `NavigationView`. Это самый просто вариант

Comment: Самый простой, но тогда придется в каждом фрагменте делать одно и то же, это не очень хорошо)

Comment: А кто вам мешает создать базовый фрагмент, со всеми общими действиями и наследовать все фрагменты с NavigationView от него

Comment: это да, но я имел в виду что в разметку для каждого фрагмента нужно добавлять DrawerLayout

Comment: А что вам мешает сделать через тег <include>

Comment: А лучше создать один layout с разметкой с NavigationView. А в него уже в базовом фрагменте инфлейте нужный layout

Comment: да, согласен, можно так сделать